# R: adding biplot arrows to CCA plot

Tags: r, plot, vegan

Starting with the following code:

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
Ordination.model1 <- cca(dune ~ Management,dune.env)
plot1 <- plot(Ordination.model1, choices=c(1,2), scaling=1)
```

I get a plot with sites, species, centroids, and biplot arrows.  I want to build up a plot with just the sites depicted by points, and the arrows with customized labels.
So far, I have:

```
colvec <- c("red", "green", "blue")
plot(Ordination.model1, type="n", scaling=1)
with(dune.env, points(Ordination.model1, display ="sites", col=colvec[Use], scaling=1, pch =16, bg = colvec[Use]))
```

I am stuck as far as how to put the arrows in.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please dput() your data, and add to the question. Thanks

Comment: Lina Bird please make sure that your example is reproducible, this way it will be easier for us to help you.  To that end please provide sample data as dww suggests.

Answer (score 2):

You can add arrows using text.  I was not able to use your code as I kept getting errors, however here is a basic example that does what you want. I took it from [R Help:  CCA Plot](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/CCA-plot-td4651048.html) 
Once you add text the arrows should show.

```
require(vegan) 
data(varespec) 
data(varechem)

vare.cca <- cca(varespec ~ ., data = varechem) 
plot(vare.cca, display = c("sites","species"), scaling = 3)
text(vare.cca, scaling = 3, display = "bp")
```

Here is an example with the labels argument:

```
## S3 method for class 'cca':
text((x, display = "sites", labels, choices = c(1, 2),
scaling = "species", arrow.mul, head.arrow = 0.05, select, const,
axis.bp = TRUE, correlation = FALSE, hill = FALSE, ...))
```

labels:
Optional text to be used instead of row names:
[Plot or Extract Results of Constrained Correspondence Analysis or Redundancy Analysis](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/vegan/docs/ade2vegancca)

Comment: Thank you!  That does add the arrows.  Is there a way to change the labels?  I added the code to retrieve the dune dataset from vegan.  the problem is that when plotting factor levels, the labels include the factor name as well.

Comment: @LinaBird have you tried labels? Here is the example:

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/vegan/docs/ade2vegancca

Comment: you can use argument `labels` to change the labels.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to rename the arrows: below is the full code.

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
Ordination.model1 <- cca(dune ~ Management,dune.env)
summary(Ordination.model1)  # Lets you see the current biplot labels in the output.
colvec <- c("red", "green", "blue", "orange")   
plot(Ordination.model1, type="n", scaling=1)
with(dune.env, points(Ordination.model1, display ="sites", col=colvec[Management],scaling=1, pch =16, bg = colvec[Management]))
labl <- c("HF", "NM", "SF")   # new labels.  Need to be in the same order as the old biplot labels.
text(Ordination.model1, display="bp", scaling=1, labels=labl)
```

Comment: You should accept your answer if that was the one you ended up using.  I'm glad you were able to figure it out.  Cheers